Trying to concatenate 2 bash variables doesn't work
Trying to concatenate 2 bash variables doesn't work.
I've got the following script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Backup WSL

bdir=/mnt/f/wslbackup/
echo Backup Dir is $bdir

rel=$('/mnt/c/program files/wsl/wsl.exe' -l -q | tr -d '\0') #removes a null char in the output
echo Release dir is $rel

ts=$(date --rfc-3339=ns | tr -d '\0' | sed 's/[\.: _-]//g') #removes all spec chars and space
echo Timestamp is $ts

echo Creating Backup File Name with backup dir, release, timestamp filename
bufile="${bdir}${rel}" #works fine
echo $bufile 

ts="/${ts}.tar"
echo $ts

echo All together...
bf="${bufile}${ts}" #doesn't work
echo $bf
# wsl --export $rel $bufile

Here is the output:
Backup WSL
Backup Dir is /mnt/f/wslbackup/
Release dir is Ubuntu-24.04
Timestamp is 202405221507454300622600400
Creating Backup File Name with backup dir, release, timestamp filename
/mnt/f/wslbackup/Ubuntu-24.04
/202405221507454300622600400.tar
All together...
/202405221507454300622600400.tar


Likely some Windows line endings (CRLF) have made their way into your script - are you sure you should not be removing \r (CR) rather than \0 (null) from the wsl.exe output?

steeldriver, OMG, that did it! TY!!!

declare -p varname is a better way to inspect variable contents.
